# When are guards alerted by nearby kills?

Tags: payday-2

For example, when trying to silently take out (shoot) a guard on the top floor of the Shadow Raid job, some times (and seemingly at random), a guard on the roof will be alerted. This then leads to the failure of the heist.

My question is about the mechanics etc. for guards being alerted. Can guards be alerted by sound through a ceiling or wall? Are silenced pistols not silent enough and should I use melee attacks instead ? Or is it a game glitch and can I simply not kill guards when there is a guard on the roof too close?

Answer (score 3):

Guards are alerted if they hear anything (running, gunshots, people being killed, etc) or see anything (body, drill, etc).   The roof guards in Shadow Raid also have a very large line of sight, which also is greater on higher difficulties.

There are ways to reduce noise, and that is where there Ghost and / or Fugitive perks come in.  If you get Shinobi or Hidden Blade aced then enemies make 95% less noise when killed, and this does make a good bit of difference.  So if you want to reduce the chance of being caught get one of those perks.  Also Winstone Wolf is good for the extra bodybag. :)

On a side note: the suppressor you add to your gun is just that, a suppressor, it doesn't block sound it just reduces it.

Comment: Also note the sound reduction is to your *shooting* sounds, but guards also have a *dying* sound.  If you melee kill you make no *shooting* sounds, but the death sound with alert nearby people.

Comment: I don't believe a guard will ever react to the firing of a suppressed gun (although they may react to its effects). From the situation described, I think the asker has neither Shinobi nor Hidden Blade aced and so the guard on the roof hears the sound of the guard on the top level dying (as you also suggest).

Comment: A guard will react to a bullet hitting a wall, or breaking glass.

Comment: @Nelson Actually, I'm fairly sure hitting a wall with a silent gun does nothing to alert the guards. Unless it changed recently. Also, I'm unsure if they react to the impact on glass or if they see the broken glass and react to that (which they do if it was broken beforehand)

Comment: The question is slightly changed since asked. To clarify, I do have hidden blade aced, and use a suppressor. To further specify, a guard a floor up heard/saw/detected my kill a **floor below**. So do the mechanics of detection work through a wall or ceiling? The dying sound etc. were already clear to me.

Comment: I know this is old, but I recall that for the purposes of noise detection, only the lateral distance is used - which means even with hidden blade / Shinobi aced, if you kill a guard and someone is either straight above or straight below that guard, the death scream of the guard will alert them because they are, for the purposes of noise detection, less than 1m away. I have no idea if this has ever been fixed (and I don't recall ever seeing that it has been fixed to use a 3D distance instead of a 2D distance).

Comment: Actually due to game mechanics - suppressors totally mute weapons in payday. Be aware that in older builds, guards would audibly scream when shot at unless you had the shinobi skill from ghost - although this is now not the case as of update 100. Basically though, suppressors reduce the hearing range on weapons to miniscule levels, its bizarre how the guards cant hear suppressed 50 caliber snipers right next to them